# Encoding unicode to latin1, replacing unavailable character with similar character

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

When there is no counterpart, a character is usually replaced with a single character, usually `"?"`. Is there a way to encode the characters, and when missing, use a similar character, e.g. `"ł"` -> `"l"`, rather than a question mark? I know both things are possible independently. I wonder if there is a solution that combines both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exemple using active support, but there are other solutions to transliterate if it is not an option for you :

```
require 'active_support'
"łé".encode(Encoding::ISO_8859_1, fallback: proc{|c| I18n.transliterate(c)})
```